# How do you select all members of a group in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How do you select all members of a group in Inkscape without doing this manually?

I have a large and detailed SVG file where manually selecting each member of a group is not practical...

Shortcuts like `select all` do not enter the groups. The sub menu that appears upon right click on a group shows no selection options.

Also `ungroup` is not practical due to the lack of a `regroup` feature in Inkscape.

Best case scenario - an option like `select all including group items` is a thing...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you **double click** (or hit Ctrl+Enter) on a group, you perform the **[Enter Group](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Groups.html)** command, which turns the group into a *temporary layer* (you know that you are entered into the group because in the layer drop down menu now appears the group name).

In this mode, the **Select All** command act only on the objects of the group (and this should answer to your question).

To exit you can **click** on an object **outside** the group (or hit Ctrl+Backspace). See also the link above.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how this can be done for multiple groups at once? I tried `select all` and then `Ctrl+Enter` which didn't work. I am trying to execute something on all the items in the svg at once.

Comment: I'm sorry, at the moment is not possible have a temporary layer for multiple groups: you need to perform your operations on each group. Btw, what kind of operation do you need to perform? In order to change background or border you can operate at group level.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! I wanted to use the Flatten Bezier extension but it operates on individual paths only.

Comment: I see... If you don't care to less groups information, you can select all, hit repeatedly **Shift-Ctrl-G** until all the groups and sub-groups are removed, and apply the Flatten Bezier extension to the paths.

Comment: I need them to remain as groups. If Inkscape had `regroup` that would have been the second thing I tried. I'll just find some good music and manually do this for the 200+ groups =P

Comment: I'm sorry, Inkscape cannot regroup. Perhaps you can [request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/) a new feature.

Comment: is there a panel of all objects in Inkscape?

Comment: @Ooker Since Rev.0.92 there is the **Objects dialog** (menu *Object*, voice *Objects*), see also [here](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Objects_Dialog).

Comment: very, very useful information to work with groups, thanks pal